# Meaning of "go around" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've come across it in the 13th episode of the 8th season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Simon: Hello again, Widow Rhee,
>
> and allow me to offer my condolences.
>
> For what's happened and what's about to happen.
>
> In case it's not already plain as Hilltop potatoes,
>
> yours truly is speaking
>
> on behalf of Negan this **go 'round**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "this time", referring to something that happens repeatedly.

[Merriam-Webster "go-round"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-round)
noun go-round
: one of a series of recurring actions or events : round

Another way to say it is "this time around".